# Google html service to sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not a big fan of google forms so I made the form for my user input in the html service. I found a way to push the data out of the form and into google sheets using all of my variables in the html file like this:

```
        <textarea type="text" name="Special Instructions" id="instructions"></textarea>
    ...
    var instructions = document.getElementById("instructions").value;
    ...
google.script.run
    .formsubmit (instructions,...)
google.script.host.close()}
```

in combination with the following in the code file:

```
function formsubmit(instructions,...)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),7,1,1).setValue(instructions);
...
```

The problem is, not only is the code very slow to output results, but if I have more than 37 or so variables defined, it glitches out and rather than closing the dialog box and recording the values in a spreadsheet, it opens a blank web page.

I know there has to be better (and more efficient) way, but I'm afraid I don't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the "client side", put all of your variables into a JSON object or an array, the stringify it, and send that string to the server.

```
var objectOfData;

variableOne = "one";
variable2 = "two";

objectOfData = {};

objectOfData['varOne'] = variableOne;//Create a new element in the object
objectOfData['var2'] = variable2;//key name is in the brackets

objectOfData = JSON.stringify(objectOfData);//Convert object to string

google.script.run
  .formsubmit(objectOfData);
```

And then convert the object as a string back to a real object:

```
function formsubmit(o) {
  var arrayOfValues,k,myData,outerArray;

  myData = JSON.parse(o);//Convert string back to object

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  arrayOfValues = [];

  for (k in myData) {//Loop through every property in the object
    thisValue = myData[k];//
    Logger.log('thisValue: ' + thisValue);//VIEW the LOGS to see print out

    arrayOfValues.push(thisValue);
  }

  outerArray = [];
  outerArray.push(arrayOfValues);

  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1,7,1,arrayOfValues.length).setValue(outerArray);
  ...
```

Note that the last parameter of `getRange('start row', start column, number of rows, number of columns)` uses the length of the inner array named arrayOfValues.  This insures that the parameter value will always be correct regardless of how the array is constructed.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Sorry it's been so long, this is a side project at work and I'm only able to devote time to it a few times a month.

So I am trying what you suggested, but struggling with the JSON.Parse, it seems to think it's undefined. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are not familiar with troubleshooting, take 5 minutes to read the troubleshooting guide at the following Google link:  [Link to Troubleshooting Information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)  At the top of the `formsubmit(o)` function, add a statement:  `Logger.log('formsubmit ran: ' + o)`  Run the code and then VIEW the LOGS.  Did `o` get passed into the function?

Comment: This tutorial looks very helpful. Thank you. I will sit down and read it and see what I can come up with. I'll let you know. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Got it! Thanks so very much. The Troubleshooting link was gold as well. I appreciate you educating a noob.