# Can't Pass WebApp Html ElementID Text to Googl Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried searching for a similar problem on here, and the closet I found was converting object to strings using Stringify and back again using Parse. ([Google html service to sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463795/google-html-service-to-sheets))

However, I am completely new to JSON and with what i'm trying to do, so I was wondering IF indeed the above will help me or not.
What I need is simple.

I have the below code for Google Sheets Script

```
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7HFp0e7AnU'
//https://codewithcurt.com/create-file-loader-google-web-app-to-google-drive/
//https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/2f16f467c94612dc83920a3158614d95

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var message = "";

function onOpen(){
  checkFolderExists();
}

function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('UploadFile');
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  var receiptFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Expense Receipts").next().getId();
  var destination_id = receiptFolder;  // ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE DIRECTORY;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);

  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameter.fileData);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.fileName);
  destination.createFile(blob);
  var url = destination.getFilesByName(e.parameter.fileName).next().getUrl();


  listRecord(e.parameter.description, e.parameter.paymentCard, e.parameter.receiptAmount, url);

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('UploadFile');
  htmlOutput.message = 'File Uploaded';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function listRecord(description, paymentCard, receiptAmount, fileURL) {
  var url = spreadsheet.getUrl();  //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var expensesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Expense Receipts");
  var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd MMM yyyy")

  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
  var localURL = '';
  localURL += SS.getUrl();
  localURL += '#gid=';
  localURL += ss.getSheetId();

  expensesSheet.appendRow([currentDate, description, paymentCard, receiptAmount, '=hyperlink("' + fileURL + '","View Receipt")']);
}

function getUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}

function showDialog() {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('UploadFile').evaluate();
  var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('Upload Expense Receipt')
    .setWidth(500)
    .setHeight(500);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Upload Expense Receipt");
}


function checkFolderExists() {
  var fileID = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId());
  var currentFolderID = fileID.getParents().next().getId();
  createFolder(currentFolderID, "Expense Receipts");
};

function createFolder(folderID, folderName) {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var subFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  var doesntExist = true;
  var newFolder = '';
  // Check if folder already exists.
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = subFolders.next();
    //If the name exists return the id of the folder
    if (folder.getName() === folderName) {
      doesntExists = false;
      newFolder = folder;
      return newFolder.getId();
    };
  };
  //If the name doesn't exists, then create a new folder
  if (doesntExists = true) {
    //If the file doesn't exists
    newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
    return newFolder.getId();
  };
};
```

And the following HTML Code:

```
<!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/
https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/
https://fontawesome.com/ -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <title>Upload New Expense Receipt</title>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
      var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    });
  </script>

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function LoadFile(event){
      var file = event.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        var fileData = e.target.result.substr(e.target.result.indexOf(",")+1);
        var mimeTypeStart = e.target.result.indexOf("data:") + 5;
        var mimeTypeEnd = e.target.result.indexOf(";");
        var mimeType = e.target.result.substr(mimeTypeStart, mimeTypeEnd - mimeTypeStart);

        //Format today's date for use generating filename
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

        var fileName = today + ' ' + document.getElementById("description").value;
        document.getElementById("fileName").value = fileName;
        // var fileName = file.name;
        document.getElementById("fileData").value = fileData;
        document.getElementById("mimeType").value = mimeType;
  
        var elemPaymentCard = document.getElementById("paymentCard");
        var paymentCard = elemPaymentCard.options[elemPaymentCard.selectedIndex].text;
        var receiptAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Upload New Expense Receipt</h4>
  <?var url = getUrl();?>
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" method="post" action="<?= url ?>">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="What was purchased" id="description" name="description" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <select id="paymentCard" name="paymentCard" class="icons">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <optgroup label="Business Cards">
              <option value="1" data-icon="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=14MCi1Uu5DXZEIBPFYiFToMOKoy2HlXj5">Business Debit Card Ending 1111</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Personal Cards">
              <option value="2" data-icon="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1elCGqEL7FeZIaUUK1bM82T78-EaC1slU">Personal Credit Card Ending 2222</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
          <label>Payment Method</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="Enter receipt amount" id="amount" name="amount" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="amount">Total Amount</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="file-field input-field">
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Select File</span>
            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="LoadFile(event)">
            <input type="hidden" id="fileData" name="fileData" />
            <input type="hidden" id="mimeType" name="mimeType" />
            <!-- <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" /> -->
          </div>
          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input placeholder="Select File" id="fileName" name="fileName" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Save Receipt
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <span><? message ?></span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Which looks like this:
[image: Before Submit]

And in Google Sheets, ends up like this:

[image: Result]

What needs to happen (that isn't), is first, the SelectedINdex's .text for the **Payment Method** Select Element (not the value -the displayed .text). For some reason the .value of the selected Index is passing instead. I "COULD" just put the value I want passing, into thee relevant value="", but I wish the values to remain 1 an 2, and instead be able to read the selected index's text.

Second, the Amount of purchase isn't passing.

Can anyone advise?

Is it possible to Add PaymentCard and PurchaseAmount to the list of parameters as i'm trying to do in the Script Code :

> listRecord(e.parameter.description, e.parameter.paymentCard,
> e.parameter.receiptAmount, url);

It SHOULD have looked like this if correctly working...

[image: Should Be this]

thank you all for your patience and support.

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my sample script was not seful for your situation. About your question, is your showing image your current issue? If my undersatnding is correct, can you add the sample of your expected situation of Spreadsheet as an image?

Comment: Hi. to confirm, you'd like me to show you a screenshot, of what I'd like it to appear like?

I've updated the main post at the bottom

Comment: P.s. Thank you for helping bud. Just saw you were the guy who created the video I'm learning from. No worries an no apologies needed. thank you for your help.

Your code is really helpful actually, my issue is I don't know how to add new elements to it.

you'll notice i've using Materialise CSS to pretty up the form :-)

Comment: Thank you for repling and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to add new "hidden" elements and set their .value to that of the textboxes the user enters (how I interpret your coded using these"hidden" elements)

However, as in the result image, you'll see that it returns "1" for the payment method, which would be the "value="" for the select dropown (no hidden elements used). I can't get it to return the text.

Comment: Thank you for repling. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. From your reply, I couldn't undersatnd whether my proposed modification was useful. If my proposed modification was not useful, I have to apologize. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Question 1:

  > What needs to happen (that isn't), is first, the SelectedINdex's .text for the Payment Method Select Element (not the value -the displayed .text). For some reason the .value of the selected Index is passing instead. I "COULD" just put the value I want passing, into thee relevant value="", but I wish the values to remain 1 an 2, and instead be able to read the selected index's text.
- Question 2:

  > Second, the Amount of purchase isn't passing.

#### Modification points:

- In the case of question 1, how about preparing an object for converting the index to the value? Because, in your script, the display value is not included in the event object.
- In the case of question 2, your HTML uses `amount` as the name. So in this case, it is required to modify this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

##### From:

```
listRecord(e.parameter.description, e.parameter.paymentCard, e.parameter.receiptAmount, url);
```

##### To:

```
var obj = {"1": "Business Debit Card Ending 1111", "2": "Personal Credit Card Ending 2222"};
listRecord(e.parameter.description, obj[e.parameter.paymentCard] || "", e.parameter.amount, url);
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: The code you recommended produced the same result :( the payment amount didn't come across, nor did the payment card :( I Reployed the App also so had a new URL

Comment: @Phil Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested your script by reflecting on my proposed modification, I confirmed that your expected image can be obtained. I deeply apologize that my proposed modification obtains your expected situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide detailed information for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: So when you tried it, it worked? I can't seem to get it to

Comment: I'm basically just entering test data and pressing submit. when I go back to sheets; it appends a new row, but looks like the result picture

Comment: @Phil Thank you for replying. About `when you tried it, it worked?`. it's yes. So in order to confirm your current situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, after you modified your Web Apps script, did you reflect the latest script to Web Apps?

Comment: I managed to get it to work, using your code; but my creating a new sheets project. I'm trying now to figure out why the original didn't work

Comment: Your code modification worked!. thank you very much my friend.